# How to validate HTML using JTidy?

Tags: java, html, validation, jtidy

I want to validate my HTML using JTidy. I want a response of true or false if it is valid or not, respectively. Currently I am using this code:

```
String htmlData = "<html><head></head><body><div>Hello Java </div></body></html>";  
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();

InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlData.getBytes());
tidy.parse(stream, System.out);
```

Is there a way to get a boolean response whether my HTML is valid or not?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation you can get total error counts for your last parse operation using [getParseErrors](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/w3c/tidy/Tidy.html#getParseErrors())

So you can do something like

```
private boolean isValid(String htmlData){
   Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
   InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlData.getBytes());
   tidy.parse(stream, System.out);
   return (tidy.getParseErrors() == 0);
}
```